# Android low memory killer & application back stack

Tags: android, process, task, back-stack

Android system may decide to remove an application process when the system is low on memory, so to reclaim resources for more important work ( ie. to start a service belongs to another application ). However, I couldn't be sure if it's possible for the Android system to remove ONLY application task ( back stack )  without touching the corresponding app process?

If this is possible, it's also possible the system destroys the back stack activities by performing a call to each onDestroy() callback. So, how can we catch this task removal just like we catch it in a Service ( through onTaskRemoved )

Thanks

Comment: This is a very good resource to read and indeed answering my question https://medium.com/google-developers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Android wants to reclaim resources (or just because Android likes to tidy up), it will usually just kill off any OS processes that are not hosting foreground activities or foreground services. Android does this by actually killing the OS process, therefore `onDestroy()` will NOT be called on any components that are active in those OS processes. You will not be warned about this, so there is no way to "catch" this behaviour.

Comment: So, it's a very brutal killing then.

Comment: Yes, and your app needs to be able to handle this gracefully, otherwise your users will uninstall your app in a heartbeat.

Comment: Am i right that ``onStop`` will trigger in any case?

Comment: Yes. Since Android 3.0 (Honeycomb), `onStop()` is guaranteed to be called before the OS process is killed.