# How long before Android kills app if RxJava Timer is running in background?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, rx-java, rx-java2

So I have an RxJava timer running in the background of the app every 30 seconds. The issue is that this timer runs, even when the app is backgrounded. My concern is whether or not the AndroidOS will kill the app eventually, even though this timer is running. I'd like the OS to ideally kill the app, and not have it be forced to stay alive due to this timer. The timer is disposed when the app is closed.

I was thinking as a solution, I could bind the lifecycle of this observable to the app being in foreground/background. That way it's paused/restarted appropriately. Right now it runs until app is killed. Here is how I setup the timer:

```
navBadgeTimerDisposable = Observable.timer(refetchIntervalMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .flatMap {
                fetchNavBadges(BADGES_TO_FETCH).toObservable()
            }
            .subscribe({
                Timber.i("android_fetch_badge_success")
                navBadge.onNext(it)
                loadNavBadges(it.refetchIntervalMs)
            }, {
                if (MAX_RETRIES > 0) {
                    Timber.w(it, "android_fetch_badge_retry")
                    MAX_RETRIES -= 1
                    loadNavBadges(DEFAULT_RETRY_INTERVAL)
                } else {
                    Timber.w(it, "android_fetch_badge_failure")
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like the OS to ideally kill the app, and not have it be forced to stay alive due to this timer.

This is not how Android operates. Android has a very complex algorithm in order to determine when an app will be killed. In most cases it will kill apps because it has to free up resources (low-memory)

For furter information please look at following resources:

- [Android low memory killer & application back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953868/android-low-memory-killer-application-back-stack)
- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle

> I was thinking as a solution, I could bind the lifecycle of this observable to the app being in foreground/background. That way it's paused/restarted appropriately.

If you do not need the timer when the app is in the background, you could just dispose the subscription in a lifecycle-callback.

There are some lifecycle callbacks, which will be called, when the system detects a low memory state. For further information please have a look at: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory

Comment: I see, yes you're right, I could dispose the timer when app is backgrounded in a lifecycle call back... However what about restarting it as well? I don't want to restart the timer accidentally twice, but I suppose I can move my timer restart logic into onResume() of a specific activity

Comment: Even though the timer is running indefinitely while app is backgrounded, this won't prevent the OS from killing the app when it decides to do so, correct? I'm just worried about any adverse side effects from the timer running in app background.

Comment: > this won't prevent the OS from killing the app; Yes;; > I could dispose the timer when app is backgrounded in a lifecycle call back; Yes. The callbacks are handled by android and have a state-machine underneath it (see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). Start the timer onResume and dispose it in onPause. This will make sure, that the time is not started twice. If you really want to make sure, just init it with Disposables.disposed() and dispose in onResume before creating the timer.